# Django filtering database with .value and calling foreign key

Tags: python, django

Once again I'm asking for your help. I want to return data in Json format from database and I need 3 values `temperature, date and sensor.description`. With little to no problem I can query and get 'temperature' and 'date' but I have hard time with getting that sensor description. This gives me temperature and date

```
sen = S280000020E3120.objects.filter(date__range=[dateo, datee]).values('date', 'temperature')
```

and this returns the description

```
desc = S280000020E3120.objects.filter(date__range=[dateo, datee]).last().sensor.description
```

And If I want to return json from that I have to do `sen = list(sen)` but when I try to append `desc` to `sen` by `result = sen.append(desc)` I got error

> NoneType object is not iterable

Is it possible to get result in similar format?

```
{
    "ds": [
              {"date": "2020-06-19T16:23:16", "temperature": "27.4"}, 
              {"date": "2020-06-19T16:26:24", "temperature": "27.4"}, 
              {..rest of data..}, 
              sensor.description
          ]
}
```

My view.py

```
def chartData(request):
    fixm = datetime.min.time()
    fixd = datetime.max.time()
    dateo = '2020-06-19'
    datee = '2020-6-20'
    dateo = datetime.strptime(dateo, '%Y-%m-%d')
    datee = datetime.strptime(datee, '%Y-%m-%d')
    dateo = datetime.combine(dateo, fixm)
    datee = datetime.combine(datee, fixd)
    sen = S280000020E3120.objects.filter(date__range=[dateo, datee])

    #date = sen.values('date', )
    value = sen.values('date', 'temperature')
    lvalue=list(value)
    senName = sen.last().sensor.sensor_name
    #lvalue = lvalue.append(senName)
    result = {
            'ds': list(lvalue),
            }
    return JsonResponse(result, safe=False)
```

models.py

```
class S280000020E3120(models.Model):
    sensor = models.ForeignKey('Sensors', models.DO_NOTHING)
    temprature = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1)
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '28-0000020e3120'

class Sensors(models.Model):
    sensor_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'sensors'
```

Output I get

```
{"ds": [{"date": "2020-06-19T16:23:16", "temperature": "27.4"}, {"date": "2020-06-19T16:26:24", "temperature": "27.4"}, {...}]}
```

Output I want or something similar when I can easily get description because this data I hope will be graph with char.js or something

```
{"ds": [{"date": "2020-06-19T16:23:16", "temperature": "27.4"}, {"date": "2020-06-19T16:26:24", "temperature": "27.4"}, , {...},sensor.description]}
```

In this example I query only one table but at the end I need get data from 8 of these if this makes it any different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your sensor model looks like, but in general, this should do the trick:

```
sen = S280000020E3120.objects.filter(date__range=[dateo, datee]).values('date','temperature','sensor__description')
```

You can use Djangos field lookup syntax here too. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

Comment: I updated models.py but your solution is what I needed. Thank you